# Salesforce OAuth Refresh Token - Invalid Scope

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites, oauth2

I'm trying to get Refresh Token as part of scope but I'm getting following error

error=invalid_scope&error_description=the%20requested%20scope%20is%20not%20available

This is my request

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=****68p.bUv86t9&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F******-developer-edition.na12.force.com%2Fredirect_uri&response_type=token&scope=full%20refresh_token

My connected App Settings,

Selected OAuth Scopes
Full access (full)
Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access

Any help? , Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming the refersh_token is available only for Web Server flow and not User Agent flow of OAuth? can someone confirm it? I get refresh token for web server flow though.

Comment: scope= refersh_token  
Allows a refresh token to be returned if you are eligible to receive one. This lets the app interact with the user’s data while the user is offline, and is synonymous with requesting offline_access.

Comment: I have selected all scope values from connected app setting but still not able to receive it.

Comment: based on the help, user agent should be able to get back a refresh token: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5